# From an email address to a quasi-random number

Tags: algorithms, random-generation

#### My Aim:

I'd like to a have a function that takes an email address and outputs a quasi-random number of 1, 2, 3, or 4.

#### A little detail:

By quasi-random number I mean that given a typical population of email addresses, the probabilities of getting a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4 are roughly equal, and that obvious systematic properties of the email address such as the domain name do not affect the probability of getting a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4.

#### A little background:

I have an online experiment written in [inquisit](http://www.millisecond.com/support/docs/v1/index.htm) where participants log in on two occasions.
I want to randomly assign participants to one of four groups.
While this is easy to do for one session (I can just use a random number generator), I need some way of remembering the allocation across sessions. 
Thus, I thought that I could extract a quasi-random group allocation from the participant email.
I'm also limited in the set of functions that I have at my disposal ([see here for full list](http://www.millisecond.com/support/docs/v3/html/language/expressions/functions.htm)).
The string functions are: tolower toupper capitalize concat
   search replaceall contains startswith
   endswith substring trim trimright
   trimleft length format evaluate

#### Initial Thoughts:

I thought about trying to extract a set of features of the email address that returned a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4 with roughly equal probabilities.
Then, I could sum these properties and get the mod 4 plus 1 of that.
Thus, assuming something like the central limit theorem, I might get close.

Possible features that came to my mind:

- length of string
- position of first "a", "b", etc.

Comment: A very interesting problem. Do you have a sample of "typical population of email addresses" at hand ? Additionally it is not guaranteed, that the email-addresses of the visitors do have the same another/different structure, but since you are only looking for an approximation.... Second question: Are you able to set the seed of the RNG ?

Comment: Sounds like you want a 'hash function': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function 
This is in the realms of computer science rather than statistics though, so I'm not sure it belongs on CrossValidated.

Comment: hmpf ;) ... I intended to write the same. @Jeromy: Especially this part of the site (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hashing_data_with_other_distributions) could be interesting for you.

Comment: @onestop Thanks for the tip about hashtags. With regards to whether the question is on topic for the site, I think random allocation of participants to groups is inherently related to study design, which in turn is related to inferences from data.

Comment: @Jeremy A hash function is not the same thing at all as a hashtag! I see your point about study design though. I admit to not reading the whole of your question properly.

Comment: Why not let email adresses index any pseudo-random sequence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look up hash functions, for example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Answer (score 3):

Why not just have a look-up table of numbers for each possible character in an email. Then concatenate the numbers to form a seed. For example,

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
....
@ 27
....
```

So abc@ccc, would be converted to 12327333. This would give you a unique seed for each person. You would then use this to generate the 1, 2, 3, 4.

---

From your question, it looks like you don't mind a "quick and dirty solution". One problem with my solution is that email addresses aren't random - for example you will probably get very few email addresses that contain the letter "z", but all email addresses contain "@".

Comment: A minor note about the above method is that there are a bunch of valid characters in email addresses - punctuation in particular - that you would want to consider if you were doing this.

Comment: @dsol: I agree. You could easily be caught out with a "+" in an email address. For a quick and dirty solution, I would probably just skip any punctuation characters that I hadn't specified in my look-up table.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to other excellent answers, I just will give a simple example in R language to show a very simple hash function, which should be good enough for this purpose. To get some email addresses as test data, I get a character vector with the emails of the maintainers of the (too many!) R packages installed on my computer:

```
library(stringr) # on CRAN 
last <- function(x) { return( x[length(x)] ) }

INST  <-  installed.packages(priority="NA", fields=c("Maintainer"))
Maintainer <- INST[, "Maintainer"]
Mlist <- str_split(Maintainer, "[[:blank:]]")
Maddr <- sapply(Mlist, FUN=last)
Maddr <- str_replace(Maddr, "[<>]", "")
Maddr <- unique(Maddr)
```

Then I define a simple function which gets some number from each character in the email address, adds them, computes the remainder modulo 4 and adds 1, so it returns always one of the results 1,2,3 or 4:

```
apply_to_each_char  <-  function(w, FUN) {
    ww <-  str_split(w, "")[[1]]
    res <- sapply(ww, FUN)
    } # END apply_to_each_char
charsum <- function(word) { # length-one char vector
    sum0 <- sum( apply_to_each_char(word, function(w) as.integer(charToRaw(w)) ))
    return( 1 + sum0 %% 4)
    } # end charsum
```

Then applying it:

```
hashes <- sapply(Maddr, charsum)
table(hashes)
hashes
  1   2   3   4 
542 511 562 552
```

and we can observe that the resulting distribution is close to uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting each character to an ascii number, multiplying them all together to force overflow, and then performing a modulus operation on the least significant digits.  If this is not pseudo-random enough, you can perform a bit-shift the numbers a bit...

-Ralph Winters

Comment: Multiplying is not the best idea, I think. Especially if your initial overflow is the regular one - modulo some power of 2. You will get a lot of factors that are even, so most of your lower bits will be 0. Adding the numbers together instead would already be a lot better. If you need even better randomness, use [some sort of hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) and use any bits of the result. If you want it to be difficult to guess anything about the outcome for people other than you, use a salted strong cryptographic hash function.

Comment: Agreed.  Just wanted to suggest idea to illustrate bit shifting in order to generate (roughly) pseudo-random numbers.